# Are containers always iterable?

Tags: python, containers, iterable

[image]

Is there a scenario where the container is not iterable, according to this graph?

Comment: Technically you could implement a container yourself that is not iterable... or are you referring to a built in abstract base class?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse, build in?

Comment: You can make a container class yourself but often you inherit from a class such as `collections.abc.ImmutableObject` (or something like that) which enforces certain abstract methods.  Basically if you inherit from an ABC that enforces iteration than for sure it is iterable but you can't always assume third part containers are iterable.

Comment: for something to be iterable there is only one requirement , it needs to  define `__iter__` method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by *always*. According to `collections.abc`

- a *container* is an object that implements `__contains__` method
- an iterable is an object that implements `__iter__` (or `__getitem__`, as a fallback)

So, theoretically, no, you can implement a container that is not an iterable. However, all standard python containers (and most containers implemented by libraries) are also iterable.

Answer (score 1):

All a container does is give you the `if x in y` and `if x not in y` syntax.

You could have like a `Range(min: float, max: float)` that implements `__contains__` as returning True for any number in the range, which would allow you to write `if 3.14 not in provided_range` etc. And that would not be iterable.

The graph is a bit misleading in suggesting that `{list, set, dict} comprehension` are the only interesting things to produce containers.